# Array object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have array object in jquery.

```
array=[];
array{Id:user.Id,Date:user.Date};
```

Now am going to pass this array object to my handler file which have n number of users. In success function now am going to change the Date for the array only for the particular user. For that i have to find whether array has the user, if yes i have to change the date. So,

```
if (jQuery.inArray(user.Id, array)) {

// code have to done

}
```

If my above code is right, Can anyone tell me how to change the date value of the user or tell me any-other simplified way?

Comment: Meant to say replace the date value into some other value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) won't find the item in this way.

I recommend to use [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead, because unfortunately jQuery does not provide a `find` function for arrays.

```
jQuery.each(array, function(index, data) {
  if (data.Id === user.Id) {
    data.Date = newDate;
    return false; // this stops the each
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this method: `jQuery.inArray("Q", arrData);`
You can get the index of you object in array. After that get the object from **index** and update it.

Comment: var user = arrData[index];
user.Value = newValue; arrData[index] = user;